# Is this derivation of the inverse Laplace transform solid?

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-transform, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I tried to recreate the proof of the inverse Laplace transform formula based on the blurry memory from an electrical engineering book I've read and I would like a real mathematician to look at it and tell me if I've omitted some little detail that electrical engineers are not told about. It goes as follows:

Let

$$
f(t) = \left\{\begin{split}&g(t),~t \in [0, +\infty),\\&0, t \in (-\infty, 0).\end{split}\right.
$$

The Laplace transform of $f(t)$ can be written as

$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}{f(t)e^{-st}}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(t)e^{-st}}dt = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{f(t)e^{-\sigma t}e^{-i\omega t}}dt = \mathcal{F}\{f(t)e^{-\sigma t}\}.
$$

Thus,

$$
f(t)e^{-\sigma t} = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}\} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}e^{i\omega t}}d\omega,
$$

and

$$
f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}e^{(\sigma + i\omega)t}}d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma + i\infty}{\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}e^{st}}dt.
$$

The thing which seems the most precarious to me is the extension of the integration range at the beginning because it relies on the fact that
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty}(0 \cdot e^{-\sigma t}) = 0,
$$

which should be fine in my mind because $0$ is a constant, and not a function which approaches zero at $-\infty$.

If something is missing, I would be very grateful for any pointers on how to make this derivation more robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development looks good.  And yes, since $f(t)\equiv 0$ for $t< 0$, we can assert that

$$\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt$$

where we assume that $f(t)e^{-\sigma t}H(t)$ is in $L^1$.  That is to say , $\int_{0}^\infty |f(t)|e^{-\sigma t}\,dt<\infty$.

Then, let $F$ repersent the Laplace Transform of $f$ as given by

$$F(s)=\mathscr{L}\{f\}(s)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-st}\,dt$$

Denoting the real and imaginary parts of $s$ be denote $\sigma$ and $\omega$, respectively, we see that

$$\begin{align}
F(s)&=F(\sigma+i\omega)\\\\
&=G_\sigma (\omega)\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-\sigma t}e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=\mathscr{F}\{g_\sigma\}(\omega)
\end{align}$$

where $G_\sigma(\omega)=F(\sigma+i\omega)$, and $g_\sigma(t)=f(t)e^{-\sigma t}$.

Next, we assume that $G_\sigma\in L^1$ and $g_\sigma$ is continuous at the point $t$..  Then, applying the Fourier Inversion Theorem, we find that

$$\begin{align}
f(t)e^{-\sigma t}&=g_\sigma(t)\\\\
&=\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{G_\sigma\}(t)\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty G_\sigma(\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\sigma+i\omega)e^{i\omega t}\,d\omega
\end{align}$$

Finally, enforcing the substitution $s=\sigma+i\omega$ such that $d\omega =\frac1i \,ds$, we arrive at the coveted Inverse Laplace Transform

$$f(t)=\frac1{2\pi i }\int_{\sigma - i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} F(s)e^{st}\,ds$$